# Android Crash on oreintation change in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've got a ViewPager running two fragments and when the orientation of the app is changed the app crashes. I'm attaching the code below.

Fragment Pager Adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = new Chemicals1();
            break;
        case 1:
            f = new Chemicals2();
            break;
        default:
            f = new Fragment();
            break;
        }

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.strChemicalsApplied);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.strRawFinished);
        default:
            return "Page " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Initilization of ViewPager

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_chemicals);

    //Set up ViewPager and allow app to hold prior pages when off screen
    ChemicalsPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.chemicals_pager);
    ChemicalsAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ChemicalsPager.setAdapter(ChemicalsAdapter);
    ChemicalsPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Layout file for ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chemicals_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    style="@style/pagerTabStrip" />
```

Logcat:

```
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{us.rns.iepareporting/us.rns.iepareporting.SwipeChemicals}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at us.rns.iepareporting.Chemicals1$GenericTextWatcher.setPhosphateUsed(Chemicals1.java:251)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at us.rns.iepareporting.Chemicals1$GenericTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(Chemicals1.java:128)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7573)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3804)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3655)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3630)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3530)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12270)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2882)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2882)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2882)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12248)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:417)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5217)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2094)
09-24 16:05:31.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19595):    ... 12 more
```

setPhosphateUsed code which causes crash :

```
private void setPhosphateUsed()
    {
        try
        {
            PhosphateReading = ((SwipeChemicals) getActivity()).getPhosphateReading();
            Double PhosphateUsed = PhosphateReading - Double.parseDouble(txtPhosphateReading.getText().toString());
            txtPhosphateUsed.setText(Double.toString(PhosphateUsed));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    }
```

Comment: What is `us.rns.iepareporting.Chemicals1$GenericTextWatcher.setPhosphateUsed(Chemicals1.java:251)`. That's your code, right? Can you please post it?

Comment: I figured out what it was. Because when it rotates the screen, not all data has been input into the form, but the textwatcher runs it's functions trying to do calculations with null values. I just added a "catch (NullPointerException e) to each try/catch statement and that fixed my issue with the crash on app rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` is being caused because the `GenericTextWatcher` is being called when the orientation changes even though the actual text value hasn't changed. Simply adding `catch (NullPointerException e) {}` will catch the error and cause the app from force closing.

Comment: True. However, for this specific situation it's probably the best way to fix it. Because there are methods set to run whenever an EditText's value is changed the application runs these whenever the orientation changes. The EditTexts have no information in them which is what is causing the application to crash upon change of orientation.

If there is a better way to do this I would be all for it, I'm just unsure of how else to fix this problem.